# Windows 7 Need To Only Keep The Most Recent 5 Files In A Folder And Delete The Rest

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to find a regular (powershell or not is ok) batch script which will maintain only the most recent 5 files in a folder, regardless of filenames. I have found a few here and there which it seems do not work or don't do what I need. I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you taken a look at cygwin?

Comment: What do you mean by maintain?  Delete everything but the 5 newest files?  What defines recent? (Last Modified Date or Create Date)  Could you link to the scripts that did not work for you?  Need more details to know what you want.

Answer (score 9):

Use the DIR command to list the files sorted by modified timestamp, descending. Use FOR /F to process the results, skipping the first 5.

From the command line, use the following to delete all but the 5 most recently modified files in the current directory:

```
for /f "skip=5 eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /o-d /tw /a-d') do @del "%F"
```

If used in a batch file, then percents need to be doubled. You also probably want to specify which folder you want to delete from.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\yourFolder" && (
  for /f "skip=5 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /tw /a-d') do del "%%F"
)
```

The batch file should not reside in the folder that is being deleted from. If it does exist in the same folder, then you need to prevent the batch file from deleting itself:

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\yourFolder" && (
  for /f "skip=5 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /o-d /tw /a-d') do if "%%~fF" neq "%~f0" del "%%F"
)
```

Comment: I would only suggest you to check if `c:\yourFolder` actually exists. If it doesn't, `pushd` will fail but the script will still continue to run, and you risk deleting files in the current folder

Comment: @fthiella - Good point. I've updated the answer as you suggested.